# Bandwidth , C/No, FEC and Link budget

Tags: rf, digital-communications, encoding

While computing Eb/No do I take data rate as the input to the FEC or do I take the data rate as the output from the FEC, i.e., with the overheads. Isn't the Eb/No implicit in the overall coding gain observed in the BER charts?

The reference Link budget I am considering is the one on this page:
https://www.amsat.org/tools-for-calculating-spacecraft-communications-link-budgets-and-other-design-issues/

Comment: this has been answered previously [see this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/564888/276605)

Comment: What I couldn't understand eventually is whether I account for it again or not? Do let me know which is the case.. to be accounted or not.